# Charge customer after subscribing to a metered billing in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

In my implementation we want the customer to be charged after his subscription. We use metered billing to keep track of usage of customer. Now the problem with metered usage, stripe bill the customer at the end of the billing period (monthy - that means billing will execute on last day of the billing period). Now we want to that the billing will start on the very beginning of the subscription. Is there a way that we can use metered billing but start on the first day of billing period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is how do you know what to charge the customer at the beginning of the billing period if they have no usage? If there is a minimum charge, what you can do is to create a standard pricing plan with the minimum charge, then create an additional metered plan and subscribe the customer to both.

An example: let's assume your charge is $0.4 per event. You can reword as "$40/month (includes first 100 events. $0.4/event after)". You can then create the plans:

- Standard recurring: $40/month
- Metered: $0.4 per unit (0 to 100 => $0; 101 to ∞ => $0.4/unit)

Once you subscribe the customer to both, the customer will be charged $40 already and at the next billing cycle will be charged any extra above the 100 events.